# Core Text to render HTML content

Tags: html, objective-c, ipad, core-text

I was wondering if is there a way to render html content using core text,
because the common UIWebView is slow as hell to load up.

I've got very basic needs:
- reading *p* tags
- reading *span* tags
- using *colors*
- using *fonts* and *sizes*

that's all.

thanks you so much!
k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok I solved this in a bit tricky way.
I implemented a HTMLParser to extract the characters that I needed to be formatted
in  a different way. than I proceeded to use the string in Core-Text.

my references were

[HTMLParser] https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser
remember that this one has a problem by parsing two tags one after another
(e.g. < p >< span >. . . < /span >< /p >)

[kickstart for CoreText]
https://github.com/jonasschnelli/I7CoreTextExample

Comment: As per your instruction its working fine,But here i have a epub file which has bunch of html file, how could i load it in this could you help me

Comment: how did you manage to display images and check the css directory and map the styles ?

Answer (score 1):

See this open-source project: https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText

It won't help you render an attributed string with Core Text, but it will help you convert HTML to an `NSAttributedString`.

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered better here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18886718/187258

No need to use DTCoreText if you're targeting iOS 7 and up (which you should be doing, by now).

Here's a reprint of the code in the answer (important flag: `NSHTMLTextDocumentType`):

```
[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] 
                                 options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                           NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)} 
                      documentAttributes:nil 
                                   error:nil];
```