# Display superscript % using NSNumberFormatter

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsnumberformatter

I'm using an NSNumberFormatter to display a percentage:

```
NSNumberFormatter *inclineFormat = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[inclineFormat setMinimumFractionDigits:1];
[inclineFormat setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterPercentStyle];
```

It's working as expected with the exception that the design team would like to see the "%" in superscript. Is there anyway to specify that using NSNumberFormatter?

I'm displaying the formatted string in a UILabel in iOS devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

% does not exist in unicode as a superscript. You will need to format the string that you want with out a % sign and overlay a smaller font UILabel to make it appear as a superscript or display the contents in a UIWebView using `<sup>%</sup>` tags. [Here is a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080175/how-to-create-subscript-characters-thats-not-in-unicode-in-ios).

Comment: Ick. That's what I was afraid of.