# Exponents in NSString

Tags: ios, string, math, text, nsstring

Is it possible to have exponents in an NSString object that will be displayed in a UITextField and a UILabel? If so, how do we do it? If not, any alternatives you might suggest?

Comment: Are you talking about superscript?

Comment: Yes superscript would be perfect!

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12813254/1730272

Comment: thanks, i was looking for something like that!

Answer (score 3):

As answered by [jrturton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/852828/jrturton) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399483/how-to-display-superscript-for-third-power-cube-characters-as-a-string-in-uilabe):

You need to include the unicode symbol for a superscripted character:

```
NSInteger number = 10; 
NSString *cubedSymbol = @"\u00B3";
NSString *tenCubed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%@",number,cubedSymbol];
```

> Plenty more fun is to be had [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b3/index.htm)

Comment: that would work, is there a way to write whatever number i want in superscript?

Comment: From what I can find, it sounds like it's possible but not as easy. Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080175/how-to-create-subscript-characters-thats-not-in-unicode-in-ios) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062696/display-superscript-using-nsnumberformatter) for the specifics.