# superscript characters in string IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, character-encoding, tableview, superscript

My app in xcode has a tableview with some product data. One of my products have a superscript e in its name. How can I use superscript characters in a string like: text<sup>e</sup>

I can get it to work with numbers: text\u2070 -> text<sup>0</sup> or text\u2071 -> text<sup>1</sup>. But how to do this with other characters?

thx!

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080175/how-to-create-subscript-characters-thats-not-in-unicode-in-ios

Comment: Use the link @JasonWang gave you. We run into exactly the same problem and we did like it said there, using a webview and html. There were no other solutions

Comment: It has some good info but I can't use something like a webview in a tableview. Is the only way to do this with a image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: NSString does not support concept of super/sub script. That's more or less a UI formatting concern.

One possible solution is to dynically add UILabels in code instead of interface builder. You can add a second UILabel with a smaller font size.

Comment: Thx for the info! A UILabel with a smaller font Looks to be the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

Add CoreText framework, import CoreText.h, and use UIlabel.attributedText - it has full support for NSAttributedString. Asked and answered repeatedly on SO already.

Answer (score 2):

> For SubScript use value for kCTSuperscriptAttributeName as @-1.
>
> As per the document
>
> @discussion Value must be a CFNumberRef. Default is int value 0. If
>   supported by the specified font, a value of 1 enables superscripting
>   and a value of -1 enables subscripting.
>
> extern const CFStringRef kCTSuperscriptAttributeName
>   CT_AVAILABLE(10_5, 3_2);

```
Example- [lblHeader setText:@“Headers [Alpha1 – text”];

        NSMutableAttributedString *headerSubscript = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithAttributedString: lblHeader.attributedText];

        [headerSubscript addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName value:@-1 range:NSMakeRange(14,1)];      

        [lblHeader setAttributedText:headerSubscript];
```