# Ensuring the symbol th in iOS appears correctly

Tags: ios, uilabel, plist

I need to have 19th century in my UILabel. But it should appear as 19th century where the th symbol is a superscript. I am entering the label using plist. How do I ensure that it appears correctly in UI?

Need some guidance on this.

Image attached:[image]

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512255/superscript-characters-in-string-ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Unicode characters `ᵗ` (U+1D57) and `ʰ` (U+02B0).

You can enter these literally as:

```
NSString *num = @"19 ᵗʰ";
```

or:

```
NSString *num = @"19\u1d57\u02b0";
```

If those don't look nice enough, using an `NSAttributedString` would be best.

Comment: from plist file also the same?

Comment: In a plist you will want to use the first form with the actual characters typed in. The `\uxxxx` format only works in an `NSString` or `char` literal.

Comment: See how it looks on a real device when you run the app. The font you see in Xcode's plist editor and what you see on the device will be different. But it may not look all that great on the device either. See what you get.

Comment: this is what it looks in the plist editor: "late 19ᵗʰ century when". Both simulator and device, it looks out of size... I will attach an image.

Comment: It all depends on the font. The characters I suggested are only close approximations to what you really want.

Comment: how to type U+1D57 in mac?

Comment: Use the Character Viewer (Edit | Special Characters).

Comment: doesn't work using the unicode strings... How about the attributed strings? Do you have the solution for that?

Comment: You can't put an attributed string in a plist. But see the unaccepted answer at the following question for how to create an `NSAttributedString` in iOS that contains a superscript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080175/how-to-create-subscript-characters-thats-not-in-unicode-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

NSAttributedString has a property for that on osx, so perhaps it will be available on ios7. for now you could either store html in your plist and display that, or store 2 strings '19' and 'th' and manually add two uilabels into the top level one and manually layout them to create the superscript effect.