# Display n as subscript

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5

I want to display n as subscript in my app when i am using unicode character for it a square is displayed on my simulator.
want to display "bn" here n must be at subscript.this might be a basic question but i cant resolve this issue as i am developing my first app. please help me out of these
Thanks in advance..

the code i tried is

```
    NSString * strstatic=@"\nb \u2099;
    GenEqn.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your Equation is ==> %@",strstatic];
```

Comment: Possible duplication of this question..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080175/how-to-create-subscript-characters-thats-not-in-unicode-in-ios

Comment: Use NSAttributedString,


  You can refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555735/how-to-make-subscripts-and-superscripts-using-nsattributedstring

Answer (score 0):

I would open up OS X's character viewer and drag the character straight into Xcode. It turns out it actually works!

Answer (score 0):

You can only use characters that are available in the font you're using. You'll either need to change font to one that has the character or change the character you're using.

Check this for adding custom fonts: [Can I embed a custom font in an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application)

Alternatively use `NSAttributedString` (Possibly with a library like [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText) depending on what versions of iOS you need to support) to specify the the text layout / formatting.