# How to type subscripts/superscripts in Xcode string literals?

Tags: xcode, format, editor

I have seen this code in Xcode editor :

[image]

How can I type these strings with different character position and font size ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With these string literals, it's not a question of character position or font size. These are special [unicode superscript/subscript characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts). If you go to the macOS keyboard preferences and choose "Show keyboard and emoji viewers in menu bar", you'll have a new option in your menu bar "Show emoji & symbols". You can then, for example, type "2" in the searchbox and you'll then see subscript and superscript rendition in the "related characters" section:

[image]

So, this is not a general subscript/subscripting feature, but dedicated unicode characters for just a few common subscripts/superscripts (e.g. "2", "x", etc.).

---

Note, if you need more fine grained control over fonts, baseline adjustments, etc., many user interface controls support the use of attributed strings, e.g.:

```
let bigFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
let smallFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)

let title = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "foo", attributes: [.font: bigFont])
title.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string: "bar", attributes: [.font: smallFont, .baselineOffset: 10]))

button.setAttributedTitle(title, for: .normal)
```

Yielding:

[image]

Or, as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12813254/1271826), you can apparently also do:

```
let string = "foobar"
let range = NSRange(location: 3, length: 3)
let title = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string)
let superscript = NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: kCTSuperscriptAttributeName as String)
title.addAttributes([superscript: 1], range: range)  // Use 1 for superscript; use -1 for subscript
```

But your code snippet is clearly just using the predefined unicode superscript/subscript characters. These various programmatic approaches can be useful, though, if you need to render something that doesn't already exist in unicode.

Comment: `. baselineOffset` shifts the text up or down - is there a way to shift the text left or right?

Comment: Looking at [`NSAttributedString.Key`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/key), I don't see any horizontal offset. Clearly you can render text wherever and however you want with a variety of techniques (such as separate labels, or if you want to go nuts, with CoreText/CoreGraphics), but you're no longer dealing with a single label with attributed string.