# xml string to human readable string iOS

Tags: ios, xml, string, uitextfield

is it possible convert xml string to human readable string? i found xmlReader tutorial but i would like to do that in my MVC is it possible?My problem is i have MasterViewController who is tableViewController and also xmlParserDelegate. i get the titles shown in tables and i want to show description from xml in DetailViewController UiTextfield.I did that in prepare for segue method;

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSString *string = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"description"];

        DetailViewController *dvc = [segue destinationViewController];
        dvc.myString = string;

    }
}
```

problem is i get this result:
[image: result]

i would like to have text without  these `<p>` and `<strong>`. 
how can i do this? What must i do to convert this string? i am quite new in iOS programming and i would be very thankful if someone help me with detail instructions.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. You could strip these HTML tags from your text string. To do this properly takes a lot of effort, but you can do some primitive solutions with regular expressions:

   ```
   NSString *htmlStrippedString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</?[a-z]+>" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch | NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
   ```
2. You could show the text string in a `UIWebView` rather than a `UILabel` or `UITextView`, thus enjoying the HTML rendition of the string.
3. You could convert this HTML to an attributed string, and then use that with your label. See [Convert HTML to NSAttributedString in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217820/convert-html-to-nsattributedstring-in-ios).

Comment: first method doesnt work i will try second and third.

Comment: @userDC If you share with us a sample of the string it didn't work with, I can probably offer suggestions. But that `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` worked for me using the string you supplied in your question.

Comment: everything works perfectly fine, i made a stupid rookie mistake. thanks again Rob