# <hr> separation in UITextView [iOS ]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

Is there a really easy way to insert an `<hr>` separation in an UITextView ?

I tried something like this, but it's not really pretty :

```
[textToInclude appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"________________________________________ \n Total: %0.3f", total]];
[self.myUITextView setText:textToInclude];
```

Comment: You sure you don't want UIWebView? You could always just render a line here you need it otherwise...

Comment: Nope, don't want it for sure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, as this UITextView as "read-only", I used an UIWebView, doing like this :

```
 NSString *contentView = [[NSString alloc] init];
 contentView = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body ><p style=\"color:grey; font-style:italic;\">Some datas</p><hr/><p style=\"font-size:14px;\">  Total: %0.3f </p></body></html>", total];
 [self.myUITextView loadHTMLString:contentView baseURL:nil];
 [self webViewDidFinishLoad:self.existingEntries];
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the content you want as HTML in an NSString.
Here's a link to some code to help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18886718/417085

Comment: Seems it doesn't work ... Because, I want to add an hr separation, not the html tag in the text..