# NSAttributedString initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error: painfully slow

Tags: html, ios, nsattributedstring, core-text

I'm using those line of codes to create an attributed string from a simple HTML string:

```
  NSDictionary *importParams = @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding) };
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *stringData = [HTML dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:stringData options:importParams documentAttributes:NULL error:&error];
```

The issue is that is really slow (about seconds on simulator)even for few characters.
I don not understand the reason behind that and I don't want to use third party libs with custom HTML parser.
Is there any other way to create attributed string from HTML text faster than this?

Comment: Can you show us an example of "html with few characters" you are trying?

Comment: Sure @"Ferty event list try <b>bold</b>" ,even if I don't add any tag is really slow

Comment: Hmm it is slow. I ran 4 in a row and the times were 0.5, 0.35,0.35,0.35 seconds for that tiny string running in Xcode 6.X iPad simulator.

Comment: You might this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217820/convert-html-to-nsattributedstring-in-ios

Comment: @ahwulf thank you for taking time by testing yourself. I will try on device to see if it a specific simulator issue. I've also read the specific link, in the comments they state the same, on iOS7 it seems to be faster but not so much.

Comment: Oh Apple you make such irritating bugs :-)

Comment: @Andrea, have you ever find a way to solve this issue? If yes, please add your thoughts.

Comment: @hagile no, I just used a plain text :(