# Converting HTML to NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring, core-text

I am working on an ePub reader and it is going pretty well so far. But I need some performance running. Currently the used API to convert HTML strings to `NSAttributedString` objects is Apple's initialization method

```
- (instancetype)initWithData:(NSData *)data options:(NSDictionary *)options documentAttributes:(NSDictionary **)dict error:(NSError **)error NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```

The only issue with this method is that, it can't be done in the background. Only on the UI/Main Thread and it takes so much running memory.

Is there some other solution that can tweak my app up a little to enhance the performance and memory utilization?

Comment: OSX has `stringWithHTML`... apparently not iOS?

Comment: None of the answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217820/convert-html-to-nsattributedstring-in-ios) helped?

Answer (score 0):

What you current code does, if by far the most efficient way.
Load html ONCE and parse it to NSAttributedString's once, save them and render inside a custom view.