# Swift - Load HTML With GIF in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift3

I have a HTML String with gif image: `<p>This is my GIF</p><img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/12K8GGWstl229G/giphy.gif">`

How can i Load my HTML String in UITextView (I can't use UIWebview in my case).

Thank you!

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18886718

Comment: Please read my title carefully! The Problem is load GIF image with HTML in TextView

Comment: Yes I understand. You can use attributed string and set it to text view.

Comment: I used your solution. But i only can load image. I can't load GIF Image