# Swift: NSAttributeString incorrect HTML result

Tags: html, ios, swift, mobile

i tried to read HTML using NSAttributeString. but it gets incorrect result when i put table in li

```html
<ol>
    <li>first 
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr> 
                    <td>hello</td> 
                    <td>: </td> 
                    <td>world</td> 
               </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </li>
    <li>second</li>
</ol>
```

and it becomes like this

[image]

i have used the other extension but it still doesn't work.

ex: [Convert HTML to NSAttributedString in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217820/convert-html-to-nsattributedstring-in-ios)

is it bug from swift? and if it's a bug is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

## Swift & HTML

First of all, think of what you want. If you want to get data from a web server, the best approach is to use PHP and (My)SQL.

#### Swift, not Objective-C

The link you provided uses Objective-C, not Swift, so it's likely not going to work. Also, when looking up things on the Internet, you should try to avoid old content, as Programming Languages change and get updated, so some things may get deprecated.
Check [this link](https://medium.com/theappspace/swift-how-to-convert-html-using-nsattributedstring-8c6ffeb7046f) for a swift tutorial.