# Rendering HTML on UITableViewCell in iOS

Tags: html, ios, swift, rendering

I need to render `HTML` which can have images, text on different cells of a `UITableView`. My datasource is of HTML content which I need to render on a `UITableViewCell` most probably.

I have also tried Attributed string on `UILabel` and `UITextView` but they also don't work great on scrolling the `UITableView`
I tried this but could not get help with different types of cell.

I also tried https://github.com/Vugla/PSHTMLView, but this has issues like it helps in dequeueing similar cells only (I need to have cells with different html)

Any help will me much appreciated.
Pointers will be also helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar use cases and was always a pain. So, I can think mainly of two options:

1. *Using the available native APIs.*

You convert the HTML to an attributed string like this (see [Convert HTML to NSAttributedString in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217820/convert-html-to-nsattributedstring-in-ios)):

```
let htmlData = NSString(string: details).data(using: String.Encoding.unicode.rawValue)
let options = [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType:
    NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html]
let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: htmlData ?? Data(),
                                                      options: options,
                                                      documentAttributes: nil)
```

However, this is slow and when used in combination with `UITableViewCell`, may lead to irratic crashes. I suppose the reason is that the native HTML parser has to load WebKit and parse the HTML on a background thread or queue, which does not play well with UITableViewCell rendering pipe line.  So, if you go down this path, I suggest to preprocess the HTML (and cache it) and let the UITableViewCell use the attributed strings as a data source.

2. *Use third party libs.*

DTCoreText (https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText) seems to solve it, but you should be aware of the licensing.

If you wish just to strip the HTML tags you could use this extension from Google https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/google-toolbox-for-mac/+/refs/heads/master/Foundation/GTMNSString+HTML.h

Comment: Ya solution 1 is a pain.      I will try solution 2 thanks for that . Can you explain what licensing are we talking abt?

Comment: I am not expert in licensing, but it seems that you have to mention the author in your app or pay 75 euros. Here is the full file: https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText/blob/develop/LICENSE The 75 euro is mentioned in the read me.

Answer (score 0):

[image][image: Add these constraints with height]Add constarint to your can use `UITextView` just add one constraint i.e height constraint with grater than and equal to property and change the constant to 999 and use following code in cell.

```
self.heightUITextView.constant = self.newStoryTextView.contentSize.height/2
```

Here `heightUITextView` is my height constraint and `newStoryTextView` is my UITextView

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! YourTableViewCell

            cell.heightUITextView.constant = self.newStoryTextView.contentSize.height/2
            cell.view.setNeedsLayout()
            return cell
    }
```

Your TableCell:

```
class YourTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var viewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

}
```

Comment: comment it. no need to use in table view if your are increasing the size of taxtview then you need refresh the main view.

Comment: you are adding image path ?