# NSAttributedString from HTML on main thread behaves as if multithreading

Tags: html, swift, multithreading, concurrency, nsattributedstring

I'm converting some HTML to an `NSAttributedString` on the main thread (the way Apple tells you to). It takes some time and then it continues executing the rest of the block.

Now, if another block is queued to run in the **main** thread too (e.g. after getting a response from an HTTP request), I would expect it to run **after** everything else is finished, but that's not what happens: they run in parallel as if they were on different threads. I did put asserts everywhere making sure it's on the main thread.

I made an experiment "Single View App" project to test this, with a file containig a very long html string like `<p>lorem</p> ipsum <b>dolor</b> <i><u>sit</u> amet</i>` and a view controller with the following code:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dispatchStuff()
        for _ in 0..<10 {
            // slowOperation()
            parseHTML()
        }
    }

    func dispatchStuff() {
        for i in 0..<10 {
            let wait = Double(i) * 0.2
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + wait) {
                assert(Thread.isMainThread, "not main thread!")
                print(" dispatched after \(wait) seconds")
            }
        }
    }

    // just loads a big lorem ipsum full of html tags
    let html: String = {
        let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "txt")!
        return try! String(contentsOfFile: filepath)
    }()

    var n = 0
    func slowOperation() {
        n += 1
        assert(Thread.isMainThread, "not main thread!")
        print("slowOperation \(n) START")
        var x = [0]
        for i in 0..<10000 {
            x.removeAll()
            for j in 0..<i {
                x.append(j)
            }
        }
        print("slowOperation \(n) END")
        print("")
    }

    var m = 0
    func parseHTML() {
        m += 1
        assert(Thread.isMainThread, "not main thread!")
        print("parseHTML \(m) START")
        let options = [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html]
        let attrString = try! NSAttributedString(data: Data(html.utf8), options: options, documentAttributes: nil)
        print("parseHTML \(m) END")
        print("")
    }
}
```

if you run it, this is what the console looks like:

[image: parseHTML() uncommented]

...all mixed together, that's the surprising (to me) behavior.

But if in `viewDidLoad()` you comment the call to `parseHTML()` and uncomment `slowOperation()`, you'll get something like this instead:

[image: slowOperation() uncommented]

...which is what I'd expect. So, what's happening here? Is my understanding of how threads work horribly wrong?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the `NSAttributedString` initializer must be doing some "run loop" calls which is allowing some of the queued up closures to run once in a while during what should be an otherwise synchronous process.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My original suspicion was correct. The implementation of `NSAttributedString init(data:options:documentAttributes:)` makes calls to `CFRunLoopRun()`. Doing so allows other queued up blocks/closures on the queue (main queue in this case) to run.

This is why you are seeing what appears to be asynchronous output on the main queue.

I put your code into a simple command line app and set a breakpoint on the `print` in `dispatchStuff`. The stack trace shows that during the call to the `NSAttributedString init` there is an internal call to `_CGRunLoopRun` which results in a call to one of the queued closures from `dispatchStuff`.

[image]

Comment: wow, that's crazy! thank you so much!! I guess I should be making the code that instantiates the attributed string be an async call with a callback to avoid unexpected behavior then :)

Comment: The documentation for the `NSAttributedString init(data:options:documentAttributes:)` states: *"The HTML importer should not be called from a background thread (that is, the options dictionary includes documentType with a value of html). It will try to synchronize with the main thread, fail, and time out. Calling it from the main thread works (but can still time out if the HTML contains references to external resources, which should be avoided at all costs)."*.

Comment: yes! this is what I meant: https://gist.github.com/maltalef/f5b95beda1acee8a1278454f2a24216f